# Adding algebraic functions to NDSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, algebraic-manipulation

I want to define an integral function which depends on a system of ODE and is also used to NDSolve the ODEs.

```
Tc = Sum[c[i]];

D[c[i], t] == r[i] c[i] (1 - Tc/k) - d[i] c[i]
```

where i = 1,...,n

Basically, I want to evaluate Tc at a given t value, before solving the differential equation for c[i] so that the code uses this value for NDSolve.

r, k and d are known parameters. c[i] needs to be calculated and thus Tc which is a summation of all c[i]s, at a give time t, is also unknown.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your question is not clear enough for me. Could you try to define your goal more carefully and which elements are known / unknown?

Comment: r, k and d are known parameters. c[i] needs to be calculated and thus Tc which is a summation of all c[i]s, at a give time t, is also unknown.

Comment: Do only `c[i] == c[i][t]` and `Tc == Tc[t]` depend on on `t`?  Looks a bit like the [replicator equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicator_equation).  Just enter the equations as you normally would for `NDSolve` -- doesn't that work?  Or define `Tc[t_] = Sum[c[i][t], {i, n}]` outside `NDSolve` and use `Tc[t]` inside `NDSolve`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: @MichaelE2 : Your solution worked too. Thanks! I defined
Tc[t] == Sum of all c[i] within the NDSolve bracket and it worked. If i define it outside the bracket as  Tc= Tc[t] == Sum of all C[i] and then use Tc in NDSolve bracket it doesn't work. weird ... I cant understand why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps

```
n = 5;
cc = Array[c[#] &, n];
Tc = Sum[c[i][t], {i, n}];
r = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n];
d = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, n];
k = RandomInteger[{1, 100}];
initcon = Table[c[i][0] == RandomInteger[{0, 10}], {i, n}]

sol = NDSolveValue[
      Join[Table[D[c[i][t], t] == r[[i]] c[i][t] (1 - Tc/k) - d[[i]] c[i][t], {i, n}],
           initcon], 
      cc, {t, 0, 10}]

Plot[Through[sol[t]], {t, 0, 10}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]